# Sending email to multiple recipients but only one will appear in the TO field

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to send an email to multiple recipients, but on the receiving end, the recipient will only see his/her email address? If so how do I do this and could you point me to some references?

I know this can be done via a loop that sends to each recipient separately. But then I'll have to consider other things as well, such as 1) server's settings: number of emails allowed to be sent per hour 2) server's settings: number of seconds interval between sending emails 3) if i add a few seconds interval (for #2) between emails, id have to worry about maximum execution time per script, because my email sending script might take minutes, if the number of recipients is large

I also know I can do a cron job for this, but was just wondering if there was a way, really, to do what I outlined in the first paragraph :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send a separate email to each recipient using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

just use the additional headers to add recipients to BCC (check out the php mail function [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php))

Comment: What what would he put in the **To** field?

Answer (score 0):

Example #4 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php (`BCC` header).
Add emails with coma delimiters.

Comment: He wants each recipient to see himself in the To field.